# Getting transaction's begin and end time - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactionscope

I have column transaction_Time_Begin and transaction_Time_End in almost all of tables in my database. I need to fill _Begin with date/time at the moment when user starts input in a new row of table, and fill _End with date/time at the moment when he press *Enter* (completes transaction).

How can I do this?

Comment: How will the *User* add a new row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do this in application code. SQL database servers don't have any useful way to know when a user presses "Enter".

Record the start and stop times you need in application code, and just include those values in INSERT or UPDATE statement.

These values will be slightly different than a SQL server's value for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, because it takes a little time (or a lot of time) for a transaction to traverse the network from client to server. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or its equivalent records the time a database transaction starts. No matter how long the transaction takes, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP stays the same.